# How can I loop through an ActiveRecord_Relation in my helpers instead of views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm trying to move a loop statement from my view that iterates with every element in a ActiveRecord_Relation and put it on my helpers.

This is the code I'm using in the views to generate a card for each post in the database:

```
<% @posts.each do |post|%>
  <div class="post-container">
    <div>
      <h2 class="m-0-p-0"><%= post.title %></h2><br/>
      <hr class="m-0-p-0" />
      <%= second_useless_helper(user_signed_in?, post) %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><%= post.body %></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But when I try to iterate through my helpers using this code:

```
def useless_loop
  @posts.each do |item|
    render inline: '<p>' + item.title + '</p>'.html_safe
  end
end
```

This is what I got instead:
[Code returned from the loop in helpers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjxg1.png)

I tried a lot of different ways of looping, but every single one returns the same thing.

The only thing that I could do was access the values of every item through bracket notation
*(Ex: @posts[0].title or @posts[4].body)*. But I failed when I tried to loop it.

I searched a lot about what is happening and why the loop does not work, but I couldn't figure it out.

The full code is available here: https://github.com/luisvinicius09/members-area/tree/app

Comment: I would use partials instead, that is really what they are for.

Comment: I agree with Eyeslandic. When you go against what you're supposed to be doing, it gets harder. Especially within frameworks. And Especially Rails.

Comment: The only reason I ignored the partials is that I thought it was considered as a view too.
But I'll take this advice next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `useless_loop` helper works fine. The reason it returns the posts collection is because [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each) returns `self`.

> ```
> def useless_loop
>   @posts.each do |item|
>     render inline: '<p>' + item.title + '</p>'.html_safe
>   end
> end
> ```

In the above the `render` call is made, but the return value of `render` is ignored since `each` does not use the return value of a block. You could use a combination of [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join) to collect all render results, then join them together into a single string.

```
def useless_loop
  @posts
    .map { |item| render inline: "<p>#{h item.title}</p>".html_safe }
    .join
    .html_safe
end
```

However there is no need for the `render` call at all.

```rb
.map { |item| render inline: "<p>#{h item.title}</p>".html_safe }
# can be replaced with
.map { |item| "<p>#{h item.title}</p>".html_safe }
```

You could also use the [`tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) helper. This helper escapes special HTML characters in unsafe strings passed as content, which removes the need to use [`html_escape`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape) (aliased as `h`).

```
def useless_loop
  @posts.map { |item| tag.p(item.title) }.join.html_safe
end
```

I'm not entirely sure if the final `.html_safe` call is needed. If all elements in an array are marked as HTML safe the resulting string might be marked as HTML safe automatically. I currently don't have a Rails environment on hand, so you'll have to test that one yourself.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your answer. I just faced a situation that the previous answer didn't work, so I tried yours & worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Builder::XMLMarkup`? ([reference](https://apidock.com/rails/Builder/XmlMarkup)) Something like:

```
def useless_loop
  html = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => 2)

  @posts.each do |post|
    html.div {
      html.div {
        html.h2(post.title)
      }
    
      html.div {
        html.h4(post.body)
      }
    }
  end

  return (html).html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [collection rendering](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections)

You can replace all the loop code with this one line, if you used partials:

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

Then create a new `views/posts/_post.html.erb` file with:

```html
  <div class="post-container">
    <div>
      <h2 class="m-0-p-0"><%= post.title %></h2><br/>
      <hr class="m-0-p-0" />
      <%= second_useless_helper(user_signed_in?, post) %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><%= post.body %></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Explanation: When you call `render @posts`, Rails will try to figure out which partial to render and will call `@posts.to_partial_path` which return the default path of a partial file that relates to `@posts`.